# How can I have a three sided border with border radius around a container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to implement this widget of an image on top and a container with a text underderneath.
[image]

The thing is that the container has a three sided border with rounded bottom corners. But flutter won't allow me to have border radius with a non-uniform Border.
here is my code:

```
 Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(4),
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: topic.image,
                    placeholder: (_, __) => ImagePlaceholder(),
                    height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2) * 1.11,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(4)),
                      border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                              width: 1, color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor),
                          right: BorderSide(
                              width: 1, color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor),
                          left: BorderSide(
                              width: 1,
                              color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor))),
                  child: Text(topic.title)),
            )
          ],
        )
```

basically I can't get the top border of the container below my image to be transparent.
and here is the exception I get:
The following assertion was thrown during paint():
A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border.

The following is not uniform:
BorderSide.color
BorderSide.width

how can i implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Container` alone isn't going to cut it here. You are going to need to come up with some sort of workaround. Here's one such workaround using a combination of `Container`, `ClipRRect`, and `Column.

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.grey,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Image(...),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8), bottomRight: Radius.circular(8)),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4, bottom: 4, right: 4),
            child: Text(...),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

You will probably want to play with it to get the sizing and layout to look how you want, but that's the general idea.

[DartPad example](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3bff1f90cf07bce66bb47d177bd058a6)

Answer (score 2):

ClipRRect is what exactly you need to know

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
        topRight: Radius.circular(15),
    ),
    // Your Image
    child: Image()
)
```

Here is the full code for your goal.

```
Column(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
              topRight: Radius.circular(15),
            ),
            child: Image.network(
              'imageUrl',
              height: 250,
              width: 300,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(40.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(40.0),
                ),
              ),
              width: 300,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 5,
                horizontal: 20,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'My Text Here',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 26,
                ),
                softWrap: true,
                overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
              ),
           ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: `Positioned` is for stacks, not columns.

Comment: I had this code for my project, I used stack there. Let me edit my answer. Thanks