# In flutter How to design rounded border side in container in a particular area?

Tags: flutter, containers, border

I need this kinds of output

[image: required this]

I try this code but this not provide rounded corner,

```
Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
         // borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(
              left: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
              right: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
            )
      
         ),
       
      )
```

how to solve this problem?

I also use borderRadious property

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
```

But this will generate an error "A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border."

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `BorderRadius.all`

```
Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 100,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
            color: Colors.white,
         ),
       
      )
```

you are getting the error becuase you are using both `border` and `borderRadius`, remove `border` and the error will be gone

Comment: I try this very first time but it gives me this error

"A borderRadius can only be given for a uniform Border."

Comment: This is not working . @Saad

Comment: you can use the ClipRRect widget to create rounded borders for your container

Comment: include `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,` on container

Comment: I need border circular, if i remove border where i found border. and also need border except top border @Saad

Comment: I did not got any solution for it, you can check these links : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/110249, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633371/give-a-borderradius-for-non-uniform-borders ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481358/how-can-i-have-a-three-sided-border-with-border-radius-around-a-container-in-flu, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72993462/container-with-3-borders-and-radiuses , these may help you